# Display an App correctly on 3.5" and 4" screen

Tags: iphone, screen-size

I almost finished to develop my App. Now I am trying to make it look nice in both iPhone 4 and 5.

I am trying to get the height of my scren but the following method doesn't work.
Any idea?

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;

if (screenSize.height == 1136) {
    NSLog(@"iphone 5");
}else if(screenSize.height  == 960){
    NSLog(@"iphone 4 retina");
}else{
    NSLog(@"iphone 4 non retina");
}
```

---

this is the complete viewWillAppear method:

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(screenSize));

if (screenSize.height == 568.0f) {
    NSLog(@"iphone 5");
}else if(screenSize.height  == 480.0f){
    NSLog(@"iphone 4 retina");
}else{
    NSLog(@"iphone 4 non retina");
}


[firstStepsButton.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
[workingButton.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
[accommodationButton.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
[universityButton.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
[meetMeButton.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
[improveYourselfButton.titleLabel setHidden:YES];

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
```

//    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:2/255.0f green:42/255.0f blue:97/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

}

Comment: You can use autoresizemask in interface builder. It is much simpler them doing it like this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't because the screen's coordinate system is in points, not pixels. Try it like this:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(screenSize));

if (screenSize.height == 568.0f) {
    NSLog(@"iphone 5");
}else if(screenSize.height  == 480.0f){
    NSLog(@"iphone 4 retina");
}else{
    NSLog(@"iphone 4 non retina");
}
```

You should also consider using UIDevice's `userInterfaceIdiom` to check whether the device is iPhone/iPad, and UIScreen's `scale` to determine whether the device is retina or not.

Comment: tried to change, but still doesn't print anything in the console.
I inserted everything into the vieWillAppear

Comment: I don't need ot check whether is an iPhone/iPad because my App will be released only for iPhone!

Comment: viewWillAppear is called because I am changing the title of some buttons and it works

Comment: i added the complete method, the stuff written in there is being called. Just the code that you gave me is not.

Comment: My mistake, I just realised that is not calling the viewWillAppear. I tried now to move it to the viewWillLoad but still nothing happens.

Comment: i think that the problem is that because showing the view I am displaying a modal view controller on top of it..

Answer (score 0):

Consider downloading Xcode 5 DP where they fixed management of Autolayout in Interface Builder. It is now really easy to set and manage constraints. Try it out.